# Rake tasks for scaling ruby apps in Heroku (non-rails)?

Tags: ruby, heroku, rake, rake-task, rakefile

I'm currently running a ruby app with:

```
heroku scale web=0
heroku scale worker=1
```

I'd like to write a rake task that will run:

```
heroku scale worker=0
```

I'm thinking of something akin to:

```
task :scale_down => :environment do
  heroku = Heroku::API.new
  heroku.post_ps_scale('worker', 0)
end
```

but one problem is that my app doesn't have an environment since it's not a rails app.  Is there a simple rake task that I can use to scale my worker to 0? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the `:environment`. Just make sure that heroku gem is loaded in that rake task

Comment: *DOH* of course.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
task :scale_down do
  heroku = Heroku::API.new(api_key: ENV['HEROKU_API_KEY'])
  heroku.post_ps_scale(ENV['APP_NAME'], 'worker', 0)
end
```

This scales the app down to 0. May want to assign that number to a config var..